# How to check Site Collection Performance in SharePoint Server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, performance

I got a complaint from client that some Site Pages loading more time display. I didnt find any hardware issue. Can anyone advice me to check performance

Environment:
1WFE server: (WFE with DC MinRole)
2APP server: (Application and Search MinRole)
We have 3 Web Applications, and 4 Custom webparts deployed

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Developer Dashboard to monitor page loading. It would tell you which part takes long time.

Reference: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/enable-developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-server-2016